# Flexbox element with flex-grow, leave space to match other items in column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I'd like the text to start at the same point in each column, but the image box is set to flex-grow: 1, which means that it will take up all the available space. I can't set a height for the image box as it's a fluid width design.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="feature"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/180/50"></div>
      <span class="caption">Caption text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
        <div class="feature">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/180/50"></div>
    <span class="caption">Longer caption text that is longer than one line</span>
  </div>  
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 360px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 180px;
}

.item .feature {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tomchambers/pen/OXXKob) with the issue.

Comment: Not possible unless the captions are always the same height.

Comment: Yes seems to be the case. Text is unlikely to be longer than 2 lines, so have gone with that.

Comment: Could you move the caption text to be inside the feature box?

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Apache Flex, the actionscript framework.  For CSS questions, use "flexbox".  I've retagged this question for you.

Comment: @Buffalo That wouldn't help.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are right, that wouldn't work unless all images had the same height.